# Windows forms control designer, adding 'task menus'

Tags: .net, controls, designer

I would like to know how to add menus similar to this to my custom controls designed in Visual Studio. http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/8702/tasksy.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called **smart-tag**.
see here: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171829.aspx)